# Starting container causes error

Tags: angular, docker

I want to dockerize my Angular application, however, I have a problem with running it in a container.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.6-alpine

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY .angular-cli.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY tslint.json ./
COPY src/ ./src/

RUN yarn install && yarn global add @angular/cli

EXPOSE 4200

ENTRYPOINT ["./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200"]
```

And here's my command how I run it:

```
$ docker run -p 4200:4200 my-notes
```

And errors in console when I start my container:

```
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200\": stat ./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200: no such file or directory"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200\": stat ./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200: no such file or directory".
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I tried to set `ENTRYPOINT` simply as `ng serve` and then container works and no errors are logged in console, but I am not able to run the app from my browser (page is not available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ENTRYPOINT` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) accepts a list of arguments. You have only placed one argument that includes the command **and** parameters.

I suggest that you replace your `ENTRYPOINT` to appear something like this - separate the arguments

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4200"]
```

---

From the "no such file" error you posted, I'm guessing that docker is attempting to locate a file called `"./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200"`, which clearly does not exist :) When you removed the other arguments, docker was able to locate the file.

Comment: It worked, but as a first argument I had to pass simply "ng". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah - very good :) Yes, you might need to have `ng` in your `PATH` for that to work - otherwise providing an absolute path to `ng` should work too.